# What this sentence means?

Tags: php, oop

i have read this sentence in the object oriented paradigm approach.

> A class can never have property values or state. Only objects can.

Can anybody elaborate this ?

Comment: A class is merely a definition.  You must actually create an object for the class to be used.

Comment: but i think class contains properties and also it has a stat

Comment: No, no. A class has no values. To use your analogy, person is a definition, and all persons will have a gender, but the idea of Person itself is genderless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a class as a definition of a new data type. As such, it cannot have a state - it's just a definition. Consider this analogy - the concept of integer can't have a value, but a specific variable of integer type may have the value of 7.